# When I download the apk from Unity to my phone to test the game, it shows "There was a problem parsing the package."

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When I try to download my game for testing to my phone from Unity it shows "There was a problem parsing the package.". What should I do? Should I change something in my code or in the export settings in Unity?
I am exporting it to a Xiaomi phone. [Unity export settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrQTL.png)

Comment: Do you try to open a new project with this settings and try to build it? maybe there is an issue with your project.
We need more detiles about your game for understand where the error come from

Comment: Turn off miui optimization first, then install your apk via `adb install`, you will see the actual error from console.